# How can I CVS-commit a binary file from command line?

Tags: cvs, binaryfiles

I need to commit a jar file in binary mode from the command line.

What command should I use? The following does not work:

```
$ cvs commit -kb -m "Committing v2.5.7" myJar.jar
Usage: cvs commit [-Rlf] [-m msg | -F logfile] [-r rev] files...
-R          Process directories recursively.
-l          Local directory only (not recursive).
-f          Force the file to be committed; disables recursion.
-F logfile  Read the log message from file.
-m msg      Log message.
-r rev      Commit to this branch or trunk revision.
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
cvs add -kb myJar.jar
cvs commit -m "Committing v2.5.7" myJar.jar
```

If you've already committed it without `-kb`, you can use

```
cvs admin -kb myJar.jar
```

You can also use `CVSROOT/cvswrappers` to specify that all `*.jar` files are binary.

Comment: tx for the 'cvs admin' tip. I tried `cvs admin -kb slides.odp` with a newly-added file and got `cvs admin: cannot admin newly added file `slides.odp'` so i mv'd the file away, cvs deleted it, mv'd it back, and 'cvs add -kb'd it.

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
cvs add -kb filename
```

then commit it